# Java, Hibernate getList not working

Tags: java, hibernate, list

I am attempting to write a website using hibernate for database access. Saving I can get working fine, however when I try and call my getList method upon executing the session.createQuery call the code just drops into the finally method without throwing an exception leaving me a bit confused!

Code is below:

```
public List<Category> getCategories() {
    //insertCategory();
    System.out.println("in get categories");
    List<Category> result = null;
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionfactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = null;
    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        Query cats = session.createQuery("from category where is_parent = 1");
        result = cats.list();
        transaction.commit();
        for (java.util.Iterator<Category> it = result.iterator();it.hasNext();){
            Category myCategory = it.next();
            System.out.println(myCategory);
        }
        calculateBlueprintSize(result.size());
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        transaction.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception ee) {
        ee.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

My insert works fine (hardcoded for now just to prove I can connect to the DB)

```
public void insertCategory() {
    Category newCat = new Category();
    newCat.setActive(new Integer(1));
    newCat.setCategoryDescription("my test category");
    newCat.setCategoryName("my cat name");
    newCat.setLastUpdatedDate(new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
    newCat.setParent(new Integer(1));
    newCat.setSequence(new Integer(1));
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionfactory().getCurrentSession();
    try {
        session.beginTransaction();

        // user.setUserId(new Long(2));
        session.save(newCat);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }

}
```

Thi is based on accessing a MySQL database.

Any help would be appreciated, I have been unable to find anything that can help me around and I am brand new to Hibernate so beginning to thinking switching back to DAO pattern using native sql with ehcache might be the best thing to do....

Thanks

Matt

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you are getting a `RuntimeException` from the `createQuery` call because you are mixing SQL names with HQL names. I assume that your table is named `category` and that the  `is_parent` column is a field in that table. If you want to use an HQL query, you need to use the name of the property on the `Category` entity, namely `parent`, instead of `is_parent`.

Comment: Thanks but even when I just have:Query cats = session.createQuery("from category"); removing the where clause it still fails :(

Comment: If you get your classpath issues taken care of, that problem will go away.